# Accessing MultipleChoiceField choices values

Tags: python, django

How do I get the choices field values and not the key from the form?

I have a form where I let the user select some user's emails for a company.
For example I have a form like this (this reason for model form is that it's inside a formset - but that is not important for now):

```
class Contacts(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Contacts, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.company = kwargs['initial']['company']
        self.fields['emails'].choices = self.company.emails
        # This produces stuff like:
        # [(1, 'email@email.com'), ...]

   emails = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
```

and I want to get the list of all selected emails in the view, something like this:

```
  form = ContactsForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
       form.cleaned_data['emails'][0] # produces 1 and not email
```

There is no `get_emails_display()` kind of method, like in the model for example. Also, a suggestion `form.fields['emails'].choices` does not work, as it gives ALL the choices, whereas I need something like `form.fields['emails'].selected_choices`?

Any ideas, or let me know if it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be a beautiful solution, but I would imagine that the display names are all still available from `form.fields['emails'].choices` so you can loop through `form.cleaned_data['emails']` and get the choice name from the field's choices.

Comment: Cool, it's actually form.fields['email'].choices. Please correct so I can accept :-)

Comment: Note above still returns a list of tuples:

[(1, 'email@email.com'), (2, 'blah@blah.com')]

Comment: Actually this is a problem, since it does Not select the "selected" options from the selection box.

Comment: What do you mean? Wouldn't the selected options be the ones in form.cleaned_data['emails']? Then you filter those not in that out of the form.fields['email'].choices?

Comment: Um.. not really. I can't see a way of doing that. ANYWAYS, I just showed the strings into the actual key-values of the choices dict.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, hopefully this is closer to what you wanted.

```
emails = filter(lambda t: t[0] in form.cleaned_data['emails'], form.fields['emails'].choices)
```

That should give you the list of selected choices that you want.

Comment: I don't see how this will work. form.fields['emails'].choices will return a list of all emails, while form.cleaned_data['emails'] returns the list of keys of only selected elements.

Comment: So, let's say you have choices = [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')] and the user selects [1, 3]. Filter does:

emails = filter(lambda t: t[0] in [1, 3], [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')])

Which returns

[(1, 'foo'), (3, 'baz')]